# Ruby: Mysql timestamp/datetime problem

Tags: mysql, ruby, datetime, timestamp, dbi

Is there solution for '0000-00-00 00:00:00' problem, without changing table?

I have "[]" in this query:

```
dbh.select_all("select j.n, j.name, j.dsc, j.flag, j.td from job j where j.td='0000-00-00 00:00:00'")
```

I look solution for this: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=22243&group_id=234&atid=967

Comment: Can you be clearer about the problem you are having?

Comment: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=22243&group_id=234&atid=967

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your default is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and you can't change it. I dug up my ruby-dbi mailing list archives and found the following explanation:

> The problem with the latter case is
>   that it can't be coerced to a DateTime
>   object because it's not a valid
>   time... Honestly, I'm surprised mysql
>   allows  it at all. Either way, you'll
>   need to turn type conversion off (see 
>   `DBI.convert_types=`) to get this
>   default value to work or change it and
>   all  occurrences of it in your
>   database, or use `bind_coltype` to treat
>   it as string  instead.

See [this mailing list archive](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/ruby-dbi-users/2008-September/000046.html).

Answer (score 0):

I usually declare my datetimes as accepting NULL, e.g.:

```
dtime DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

That way I can check if a field IS NULL rather than if a field = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast the "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to NULL:

SELECT IF(mytime="0000-00-00 00:00:00",NULL,mytime) FROM mytable;